# Make all properties enumerable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have an Error object: `new Error('foo')`

I want to serialize it, the problem is the stack/message properties are not enumerable.

So I want to do something like this:

```
const json = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, new Error('foo')));
```

but this copies the properties and they remain non-enumerable, which means they won't get serialized.
So my question is - is there a way to copy the properities but make them all enumerable, something like so:

```
const v = {};

for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(new Error('foo')){
  Object.defineProperty(v, key, {
        value: val,
        enumerable: true
   })
}
```

is there some way to do that for just two properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the enumerable properties with spread and then manually add in the `stack` and `message` properties:

```
const err = new Error('foo');
const errorWithEnumerableStackAndMessage = { ...err, err.stack, err.message };
```

For a more general solution, to create a new object with enumerable properties, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```js
const toEnumerable = (obj) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).map(prop => [prop, obj[prop]])
  );
};

console.log(toEnumerable(new Error('foo')));
```