# how to copy all own properties from arbitrary object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this test script:

```
const n = new Error('foo');
n.bar = 'bar';
console.log(n); // doesn't show {stack: "", message:"" }

const x = Object.assign({}, n)
console.log(x); //{ bar: 'bar' }

console.log(x instanceof Error);  // false
```

what I would like to do is this:

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, new Error('foo'))) //  {message:"foo", stack:"foo..."}
```

is there a well-defined way to accomplish this? I assume Error has some overrides to make properties non-enumerable and also some override to dictate how it's printed to console.

Note that if this was just for Error, I would just deconstruct it manually myself:

```
const v = {...e, message: e.message, stack: e.stack,}
```

but I would like to do same thing for other objects besides Error.

Comment: Maybe try configure the message and stack property `Object.defineProperties(c, {'message':{enumerable: true}, 'stack': {enumerable: true}})`

Comment: You don't want the `name` property?  e.g. if the original `error` was an instance of `TypeError`, then `error.name` would be `"TypeError"` — yet this is a property of the prototype and not the instance.

Comment: As [currently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77381089/2) written, it's unclear what's being asked. Is the question about formatting console output so that non-enumerable properties can be seen (as addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10729276/438273) question)? Or is it about copying non-enumerable properties (as addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58036450/438273) question)?

Comment: it's hard to phrase the question but I think the title is good - it's about copying properties to a new obj so that (a) when printed to console and (b) if send over wire to client you wouldn't have a lossy thing going, ya? what I just said is the end-goal, but I think it's solved by being able to copy all props to a new object and make those enumerable (which I guess they are by default).

Comment: There's also `JSON.stringify(n, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(n))` since `stringify` accepts an array of properties to enumerate as a second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy own property descriptors. To make an identical copy use `structuredClone()`.

```js
const n = new Error('foo');
n.bar = 'bar';

const copy = Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(n));

console.log(copy.message);

const copy2 = structuredClone(n);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(copy2).constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's as simple as this:

```
  const v = {} as any;

  for(const k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)){
    v[k]= e[k];
  }

  return v;
```

there is also this which may copy non-enumerable properties whereas the above doesn't?

```
  const v = {} as any;

  const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(e);

  for (const propertyName in descriptors) {
    if (descriptors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {

      v[propertyName] = e[propertyName];
    }
  }

  return v;
```

if this is not sufficient, please add a comment.